# PHP: Estructuras para la navegación web

Tags: php

Para la navegación a través de mi página web utilizo una estructura que me enseñó un profesor de programación no muy ortodoxo que tuve y que se coloca en el index, tal que así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            if($_GET['fichero']) $archivo = $_GET['fichero'];
            else $archivo = 'global.php';

            include($archivo);

        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Pudiendo ser `global.php` cualquier archivo que quieres que aparezca por defecto al entrar a la web.

Esta estructura sirve para evitar repetir código en cada archivo que compone la página, porque por ejemplo sólo es necesario iniciar sesión o hacer referencia a Bootstrap, jQuery, etc., en el index, o si la web siempre tiene el mismo pie o el mismo encabezado independientemente de la sección, con incluirlos aquí una vez es suficiente... pero a la vez debido al uso de `$_GET`, las URLs quedan bastante feas, además de que si no se es cuidadoso supongo que podría suponer un problema de seguridad:

```
.../index.php?fichero=decadas.php
.../index.php?fichero=registro.php
.../index.php?fichero=perfil.php
```

Simplemente quería conocer vuestra opinión acerca de este asunto, si os parece un buen método, cuáles usáis vosotros, y sobre todo si hay alguna forma de "embellecer" las URLs.